# Binding generated items

Tags: c#, database, xaml, binding, windows-store-apps

Hello I want to make a training and nutrition diary windows store App in WPF.

I have a problem, so I have a main `ListView`, you can see  generated items.
the template looks like

```
<StackPanel>
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}">
     <TextBlock Text="Training">

     <ListView ItemSource"">
     <TextBlock Text="Nutrition">
     <ListView ItemSource="">
<StackPanel>
```

how to bind in to the `ListView`s whats are in generated items?
What type of database should I use, because the number of the training items and nutrition items are variable.

I tried to use a class `sampledata` where I created a string for date and 2 string arrays, one for the training one for the nutrition but it doesn't worked.

here is the image:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are considering to use the MVVM you can use the [Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and Generate your Items in your ViewModel

[Example Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364917/assist-me-to-define-ui-in-xaml/14366819#14366819)

for such a small personal project i would prefer an MySQL database hosted by any FreeHoster ... and when your start to sell the project maybe a Full MSSQL database

Comment: could you send me the example project?

Comment: Email is Out. The Example Project i send to you contains
Bindungs,
Commands,
MVVM and
Validation